# How to make a direct link like this mysite.com/whats-new/page/2

Tags: wordpress, url, optimization, woocommerce, pagination

Can you help me
My site has added pages, with the name "what's new"
and I add this code

```
[recent_products category = "bundles, graphic" columns = "3" orderby = "date" order = "DESC" operator = "NOT IN" paginate = true per_page = 18]
```

and it works just fine, so what happens is the problem,
basic page link

> mysite.com/whats-new/

but when I go to page 2, the link becomes like this

> mysite.com/whats-new/?product-page=2

how to make a direct link like this

> mysite.com/whats-new/page/2

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In your WordPress admin Permalinks settings, set "Common Settings" to "Post name".

Comment: I looked in the settings

General Settings – Posting Name

Product permalinks – Custom base (products)


and I’ve deactivated the SEO plugin
but the problem still occurs /?product-page=2. not /page/2
is there another way

Comment: the problem is only on the page that I added,
if for the default woocommerce page it works fine like this
mysite.com/store/page/2
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared Woocommerce support in your theme?

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help,
I do not understand, because I am not a developer.
I use this theme,https://github.com/weDevsOfficial/dokan-theme